# Flash on KeyPress event preventing input text

Tags: flash, textbox, keypress

For a couple of buttons, I have things like this:

```
on (release, keyPress "l") {
    if (!editMode) {
        toggle_logo();
    }
}
```

My goal is to prevent the buttons from accidentally being triggered when the user is editing a particular textbox, and that works. However, the keys assigned to these buttons seem to prevent those letters from being typed into the Input Text box. e.g. If I try to type 'l' in the box, nothing happens, but other letters work fine.

So how would I go about overcoming this?

Comment: Did you tried to disable ( or even hide ) buttons when user is editing the textbox ?

Comment: I was trying not to if I didn't have to, but I could.